# Is it possible to have a generic Razor view to work with a generic model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, razor

I'm working on a list generator using MVC.Net.

I have created `ColumnInfo<T>` and  `Report<T>` classes as follows:

```
public class ColumnInfo<T>
{
       public string Title{get;set;}
       public Func<T,object> Projector{get;set;}
}

public class Report<T>
{
   public IList<ColumnInfo<T>> Header{get;set;}
   public IQueryable<T> Result{get;set;} 
    ......
}
```

What I'd like to do is to create the header and the body of a `Report` by enumerating its `Header` in a partial view.
The question is : How to introduce my generic `Report<T>` to a Razor view?
Here's what I have in mind:

```
@foreach(var row in Model.Result)
          {    
<tr>
    @foreach(var col in Model.Header)
    {

             <td>@col.Projector(row)</td>

    }
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to use a dynamic as your generic type in your view:

```
@model Models.Report<dynamic>
```

Your controller also needs to set the type as dynamic:

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
    var viewModel = new Report<dynamic>();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Not sure if this solution suits your problem, but I've noticed it's not possible to just set: `@model Models.Report<T>`